# Check if UUID is included in pastebin

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, compare, uuid

I would like for to check if my UUID is includedin my pastebin.

Any idea how I can check that in JavaScript?

The code to actually get the UUID is this:

```
// GET UUID

const execSync = require("child_process").execSync;
const { type } = require("os");
const { SSL_OP_EPHEMERAL_RSA } = require("constants");
let response = execSync("wmic csproduct get uuid");
let serial = String(response).split("\n")[1];
console.log(serial);

async function fetchText() {
  let response = await fetch("https://pastebin.com/raw/4hxgLxyd");
  let data = await response.text();

  console.log(data.indexOf(serial));

  if (data.indexOf(serial) !== -1) {
    console.log("included");
  } else {
    console.log("not included");
  }
}
fetchText();
```

I am new to JS - in Python I know how to check it with a request command.

Anyone knows how to handle this in JS maybe?

---

As requested my Python code:

```
def init(): # check HWID
    try:
        HWID = subprocess.check_output('wmic csproduct get uuid').decode().split('\n')[1].strip()
    except:
        cmd = "system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | grep 'Serial Number' | awk '{print $4}'"
        result = subprocess.run(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, check=True)
        HWID = result.stdout.decode().strip()
        
    print('Checking license...') 

# -------------------------------------------
# Below this - I need the code for JavaScript
# -------------------------------------------

    r = requests.get('https://pastebin.com/xxx')

    try:
        if HWID in r.text:
            pass
        else:
            print('[ERROR] HWID not registered!')
            print(f'HWID: {HWID}')
            time.sleep(5)
            sys.exit(0)
    except:
        print('[ERROR] Failed to initiate')
        time.sleep(5)
        sys.exit(0)

    print(f'HWID: {HWID}')
    print('--- License is valid ---')
```

Comment: Could you perhaps share your working python code? It may help folks to better understand the requested functionality.

Comment: sure, added @omkarbhagat

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, you can use [`indexOf`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) to search for the occurrence of a string. The function will return -1 if it does not exist, otherwise the index the first occurrence.

Additionally, make sure you account for things like case sensitivity and placement of dashes and whitespace.

```js
var str = "Hello world, welcome to the universe.";
var n = str.indexOf("welcome");
```

See the Node.Js [documentation](https://nodejs.dev/learn/making-http-requests-with-nodejs) for performing the http request.

```js
// GET UUID

const execSync = require("child_process").execSync;
const response = execSync("wmic csproduct get uuid");
const serial = String(response).split("\n")[1].replace("-", "").trim().toLowerCase();

const https = require('https')
const options = {
  hostname: 'pastebin.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/xxx',
  method: 'GET'
}

const req = https.request(options, res => {
  console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)

  res.on('data', d => {
    var dnorm= d.replace("-", "").trim().toLowerCase();
    process.stdout.write(dnorm.indexOf(serial))
  })
})

req.on('error', error => {
  console.error(error)
})

req.end()
```

Since it appears you are having a whitespace or encoding issue, please manually compare the contents of the string:

```js
function debugComp(a, b)
    {
      a= a.toString().trim();
      b= a.toString().trim();
      console.log("a: '" + a + "' - Length: " + a.length);
      console.log("b: '" + b + "' - Length: " + b.length);
      if(a.indexOf(b)>-1)
      {
        console.log("Found at index " + a.indexOf(b)); 
      }
      else if(a.length==b.length)
      {
         for(var i=0; i< a.length; i++)
         {
             console.log("a[" + i + "]= '" + a[i] + "' - b[" + i + "] = '" + b[i]);
             console.log("a[" + i + "] == b[" + i+ "] = " + (a[i]==b[i]));          
         }
      }
      else {
        console.log("Strings have different lengths");
      }
    }

    debugComp("D340D9AE-A43F-DF47-AFED-A93222AB3646", "D340D9AE-A43F-DF47-AFED-A93222AB3646");
```

Comment: thanks but it did not solve the issue.

I have edited my initial post to what I got now. But for some reason when I check with indexOf it says -1 but data and serial are both strings and serial is clearly included in data.

Comment: Can you do a console.log on the data and the serial, I would suspect that there is either a case sensitive issue or an issue with one having dashes vs one not.

Comment: sure mate, here it is:

UUID: D340D9AE-A43F-DF47-AFED-A93222AB3646
  
data: D340D9AE-A43F-DF47-AFED-A93222AB3646

serial: D340D9AE-A43F-DF47-AFED-A93222AB3646

indexOf: -1

Comment: Maybe there is whitespace. Try also using `trim()`

Comment: Did, also tried the split + join variant. Can’t see the mistake tbh

Comment: Highly surprised if it is not a whitespace issue at this point. Try logging the strings for all sources with quotes. eg `log("'" + value + "'");`. Short of that, the only other thing would be difference of text encoding between the strings. You can manually debug the difference.

Comment: Thanks for your help mate. I will try that tonight

Comment: ok I hardcoded the serial as ```let serial = 'D340D9AE-A43F-DF47-AFED-A93222AB3646' and then it worked. So I need to find a way in my coding to set the encoding for serial and data to the same.